# $\sigma$ is a permutation of $\mathbb{N}$,then the sum $\sum\sigma(n)/n^2$ ,$N<n<4N$

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, permutations

The options are :

(a)$\sigma$ is only an injective function then also the sum is convergent

(b) the sum is bounded above

(c) the sum is bounded below

(d) has 0.125 as a lower bound

Now I think options (c) is correct as it will be bounded by 0.Next I think is that the (d) is not true because if I take $N=10,00,000$ then the sum has to be very large to get to $0.125$.Since the sum is finite I think (b) is true.This  has been my attempt.

Also what I wanted to ask is there a general way to find all the permutations on $\mathbb{N}$

Comment: There is an uncountably infinite number of permutations  of the natural numbers $\mathbb N$

Comment: If you want to have a lower bound, then it is enough to think which is the set of $3N-1$ numbers such that the sum gets as small as possible. You simply have to take the $3N-1$ smallest numbers (i.e. $\{ 1, \dots, 3N-1\}$) and think which order makes the sum the smallest.

Comment: I would try to see what happens if you swap two neighboring terms and then try to get to the minimum this way (it's already too late for me try it).

Comment: Just to clarify, the given sum is a finite sum, i.e. $\Sigma \,\sigma(n)/n = \sum\limits_{n=1}^N \, \sigma(n)/n$, correct?  If not, what is $N$?

Comment: @SelarachDunbar $n $ is from Nto 4N

Comment: $\sigma$ is a permutation and is hence injective, so why would option (a) repeat this as a hypothesis?